# GCD logical error

Tags: c, greatest-common-divisor

I wrote this code to get the gcd in c. It works perfectly for small numbers
but when I tried 60 and 90 for example I got 2, while getting 3 for 9 &6.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main()
{
    int a,b,x,gcd;
    printf("Please Enter the fraction");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if(b%a == 0)
        gcd =a;
    else
    {
        x=a;
        while(--x>1)
        {
            if (a%x == 0 && b%x==0)
            {  
                 gcd =x;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("GCD = %d", gcd);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As usual, the best improvements comes from choosing the better algorithm. In this case you should use Euclidians algorithm for the GCD: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
int main()
{
    int a,b,x,gcd;
    printf("Please Enter the fraction");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    if(b%a == 0)
        gcd =a;
    else
    {
        x=a;
        while(--x>1)
        {
            if (a%x == 0 && b%x==0){
                gcd =x;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("GCD = %d", gcd);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when you find the gcd you must break the loop
//Otherwise you can use this recursive function

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if ( a == 0 ) {
        return b;
    } else {
        return gcd(b%a, a);
    }
}
```

Comment: An answer with only a code and no description about what was the error in the original code and no description about the changes you made is not very good.

Comment: Thanks for the info, i was just worried of be the first in solve the question.

Comment: Being the first to solve is not too important. If you post a good and detailed answer, it will be more helpful than a hastily made code only answer which might leave the OP confused about what he did wrong and what changes were made to it

Answer (score 4):

You need to break the loop if the condition in the second `if` is true. Just add `break;` in the body of the second `if`:

```
if (a%x == 0 && b%x==0)
  gcd =x;
```

should be

```
if (a%x == 0 && b%x==0)
{
  gcd =x;
  break;
}
```

Otherwise the loop goes on and finds the lowest-common-divisor greater than 1.